# How to convert plain text to hashed password in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I am new to Django. Already migrated from SQLite to MySQL. User related information is stored in auth_user table.

I have 100 user related usernames and passwords in plain text. I need to insert them into auth_user table. How can I do that?

For example, I am inserting them manually with below insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO `auth_user` (username, `password`, is_superuser ) 
VALUES ('test', 'test_password', 0)
```

If I insert them like that, I will expose plain text password. I want to use Django hash password.

Comment: Was this site made with Django or migrated to Django. If it was made in Django I have to ask why you would go out of your way to store passwords in plain text.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have let your users down badly by storing their passwords in plain text, but as they say better late than never.

I presume you have your users in a table other than auth_user (coming from [django.contrib.auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/)). Iterate through that table and create User instances for each user.

Call the [set_password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password) method to generate the hashed password.

> Sets the user’s password to the given raw string, taking care of the
>   password hashing. Doesn’t save the User object.
>
> When the raw_password is None, the password will be set to an unusable
>   password, as if set_unusable_password() were used.

Comment: Please  give me a example code for that. I don't know that django. I am very new to django

Comment: Sorry but as you know, that's not how stackoverflow works. Please make an attempt using the guideline given above, then if you run into a problem please post a new question with that.

Comment: Besides it's impossible for anyone to post sample code because you haven't posted what your existing models are like etc. So please make an attempt and then post a new question if you get into difficulties

Comment: Glad to have helped. If you have to post a new question, add a comment here with the link in case I miss it.